# BitmapImage in UWP display wrong images occasionally

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, bitmapimage

I use `BitmapImage` when I display avatars in my UWP app. Sometimes the avatars display wrong images (sometimes wrong size and sometimes even displaying images that I have never used in my app).

I have been googling around for a while and found few people having the same problem but none of them is solved. For example, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/174341/uwp-why-do-images-sometimes-load-wrong-source.html) and [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/153224/uwp-occasionally-an-image-will-display-the-wrong-source-using-the-bounds-of-the-correct-source).

The following is the code in my app:

**.xaml**

```
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="{x:Bind Patient.Gender, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource GenderToAvatarConverter}}" />
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

**GenderToAvatarConverter.cs**

```
public sealed class GenderToAvatarConverter : IValueConverter 
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var imagePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/Avatar/Default.png";
        if ((string)value == Gender.MALE.ToString())
        {
            imagePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/Avatar/Man.png";
        }
        else if((string)value == Gender.FEMALE.ToString())
        {
            imagePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/Avatar/Woman.png";
        }

        return new Uri(imagePath);
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[**Displaying normally**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umpyx.jpg)

[**Displaying wrong images**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16881.png)

[**Displaying wrong images again**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csgzZ.png)

It would be highly appreciated if someone can solve this problem or how to reproduce it.

Comment: Why you compare they as string? (Gender)value and then you can use switch.

Comment: This is because it could be problematic if we cast a ```value``` which is not in ```Gender```. Moreover, ```Patient.Gender``` is also a ```string```.

Comment: I tested your code in my side, and the situation displaying wrong images was not reproduced. Could you please provide us a [mcve] by OneDrive or GitHub for testing?

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT I don't really know how to reproduce it on purpose so I can't provide you the sample. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Could you please tell me whether there are a large amount of images displayed in your UWP app? If you have a many images, have you done operations on images after images are displayed?

Comment: @YanGu This looks like its an issue with how BitmapImage checks the cache when creating an image, maybe it should look at a hash of the image, or have an option to disable cache?

Answer (score 0):

Heres a way I found to reproduce it.

I have an application where there are users, and a user can have images. When you upload an image, it is saved as 0.png. The BitmapImage loads this, and displays it. Then I delete the image, so the images folder is empty. I then add a new image, which is saved as 0.png. The two images are different, but the paths are the same, and the BitmapImage control continues to display the same image.

From this, I assume that when you create a BitmapImage from a path, it first checks somewhere else to see if the image has already been created, and uses the cache instead. (I also noticed you can only create a BitmapImage on the UI thread).

To work around this, I found you can create a new BitmapImage, and load it from a stream, and the image will not be found in the cache.

Just add a converter:

```
  public class ImageToBitmapImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

            if (value is Image)
            {
                Image image = (Image)value;

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(memoryStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
                }

            }

            if (value is string)
            {
                using (FileStream file = new FileStream((string)value, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    IRandomAccessStream fileStream = file.AsRandomAccessStream();
                    bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
                    fileStream.Dispose();
                }
            }

            return bitmapImage;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And use it like:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:ImageToBitmapImageConverter x:Key="ImageToBitmapImageConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<Image Source="{Binding CroppedImagePath, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ImageToBitmapImageConverter}}"/ >
```