# Wrong images loaded

Tags: c#, image, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I was developing an UWP app. I am using UWP "Image" control to show images in my app. All images are loaded properly most of the time. But occasionally few images not loading properly. Sometimes it is loaded in cropped version and sometimes loaded a black box which is never set from app. My code to set image:

XAML:

```xml
<Image x:Name="FavoritePen" 
       Source="{Binding FavPenSource, Mode=OneWay}"
       Height="44"
       Width="44"
       Margin="0,10,10,0"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

CS:

```cs
private string favPenSource = 
    "ms-appx:///Assets/Images/NoteList/ic_main_tb_favorite_on.svg";

public string FavPenSource
{
    get
    {
        return favPenSource;
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref favPenSource, value);
    }
}
```

Black box loaded:

[image: Black box loaded]

Wrong image loaded with cropped version:

[image]

**Additionally, this is a very rare case, may be 1/100 frequency.**

I googled and tried many solutions but it didn't help. I found that some people faced same issue but didn't find a proper solution yet. ([Issue_1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/240931/bitmapimage-in-uwp-display-wrong-images-occasional.html) , [Issue_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65824443/bitmapimage-in-uwp-display-wrong-images-occasionally), [Issue_3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/174341/uwp-why-do-images-sometimes-load-wrong-source.html) , [Issue_4](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/153224/uwp-occasionally-an-image-will-display-the-wrong-source-using-the-bounds-of-the-correct-source))

Can anyone please help me to solve the issue!!

Answer (score 1):

Add View Box element, This is the x, y coordinates of the image inside the element along with the height and width. The default size is 300×150 size. Since I do not see the full container source, check if the SVG element is not beyond the parent container. You can remove the Horizontal/Vertical Alignment.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes it is loaded in cropped version and sometimes loaded a black box which is never set from app. My code to set image:

The problem is the svg file has been specified height and width property, when you render them with fix size image control, the svg content will display beyond the bound.

For this problem, please edit svg content and set it's height and width property as `auto`

```
<svg width="auto" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 469 476" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Comment: height-width of svg image already set to auto. Moreover, the cropped image is not which I set from code. It is some another image which I never used for this control.

Comment: Could you share that wrong svg image  below?

Comment: 2nd image of my main post is wrong image which is never set from *.cs but present in application for another control. The wrong image's height-width is also set to auto.

Comment: @AbuRaihan, And please check it has bee set viewBox property like above

Comment: svg image source code for all images are following this: `<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="auto" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233214/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-abu-raihan).